# Is there any difference to run docker command between in wsl mode and cmd mode?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed `wsl`and running `wsl2` (with Ubuntu) in windows 11 and Docker Desktop to play with docker.

I am curious if there is any difference to run `docker command` such as `docker build` between in cmd or in wsl mode?

wsl mode means: I enter `wsl` before running anything in the cmd.

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've installed native Docker packages inside Ubuntu (e.g. with `apt`) then Docker is unavailable in the Windows host so you can't even run commands from there.

If you've installed Docker Desktop on Windows (the recommended setup) then you're effectively getting integration between both OSes so it doesn't really matter which environment you use. In fact the Linux binaries are wrappers provided by the bundle:

```sh
$ ls -al $(which docker)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Aug 23 10:40 /usr/bin/docker -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker
```

Comment: Thanks. so, is there any difference to build an image(`docker build`) inside `Ubuntu` or in the window file system?

Comment: It's all the same command with the same images, volumes, networks... What does matter is what filesystem you use to host your files: generally speaking, it needs to be in the WSL2 Linux filesystem; if you use the Windows filesystem you'll hit bugs and performance issues.